# Flutter - Firebase Dynamic Link Fallback Url not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic links to build a link and it is working fine and redirecting user to the app if app is installed on android device.
I want users to redirect to my website if app is not installed in device or if they are on desktop and I added a fallback url with `ofl` parameter in url but it is not working.

I even tried adding `fallbackUri` in `AndroidParameters` but that also doesn't work. This link on android device redirects user to play store and on desktop simply fails because it is not loading proper url.
How can I fix this?

```
static Future<String> getDynamicLink(
    String path,
    final String? title,
    final String? description,
    final String? imageUrl, {
    final String? fallbackUrl,
  }) async {
    Uri? uri;
    if (imageUrl != null) {
      uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
    }
    String url = 'https://${ApplicationConstants.packageName}?link=$path';
    if (fallbackUrl != null) {
      url = '$url&ofl=$fallbackUrl';
    }
    print(url);
    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      link: Uri.parse(url),
      uriPrefix: ApplicationConstants.uriPrefix,
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: ApplicationConstants.packageName,
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
        title: title,
        imageUrl: uri,
        description: description,
      ),
    );
    final dynamicLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(dynamicLinkParams);
    print(dynamicLink.shortUrl.toString());
    return dynamicLink.shortUrl.toString();
  }
```